# What nginx server config exactly should be for Nuxt.js Universal project?

Tags: nginx, vue.js, nuxt.js, pm2, nuxt-edge

I've got big troubles with deploy my nuxt.js project on Ubuntu with Nginx;

```
Ubuntu 18.04 + nginx
Nuxt.js 2.3.2 (universal mode)
```

So maybe somebody can help me to resolve my problem)

I will to describe all things around this problem below:

[My nuxt.conf build part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Ptx.png)

[My nginx config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqHCk.png)

Then I run this command in ssh

```
sudo npm run build
sudo pm2 start npm --name "nuxt" -- start
```

Now server is listening localhost:3000, as I wrote in package.json

After all this I've got 500 error in console, when I open my site.
[Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txzS7.png)

nginx error.log

```
2018/11/26 04:48:42 [error] 15032#15032: *5773 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 173.267.244.9, server: example.com, request: "GET /seller HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/seller", host: "example.com"
2018/11/26 04:48:42 [error] 15032#15032: *5773 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.267.244.9, server: example.com, request: "GET /seller HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/seller", host: "example.com"
2018/11/26 04:48:43 [error] 15032#15032: *5773 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 173.267.244.9, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/seller"
```

So now I have no idea whats wrong with that. Help me please.

Comment: Hello, did you check in nginx error / access logs ?

Comment: Now it gives 502 Bad getaway

Comment: My error logs:

2018/11/26 04:48:42 [error] 15032#15032: *5773 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 173.267.244.9, server: example.com, request: "GET /seller HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/seller", host: "example.com"

Comment: 2018/11/26 04:48:42 [error] 15032#15032: *5773 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.267.244.9, server: example.com, request: "GET /seller HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/seller", host: "example.com"

Comment: 2018/11/26 04:48:43 [error] 15032#15032: *5773 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 173.267.244.9, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/seller"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Nginx tries to connect on the IPv6 loopback [::1], and nodejs is probably just listening on IPv4.

Try setting `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`